# How to get current class after typecasting?

Tags: java

How can I report what class the current variable has been typecasted to at runtime? getClass() tells you only what the original class type was on creation. Consider:

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String fu = "Hello World!";
        Object bar = (Object) fu;

        System.out.println(fu.getClass());
        System.out.println(bar.getClass()); 
    }
  }
```

Outputs:

class java.lang.String

class java.lang.String

How can I determine that bar is typecast to Object at runtime? I'm hoping for a generic solution in the spirit of getClass(), not just one that tests bar against class Object explicitly if possible.

Comment: Typecasting basically _doesn't exist_ from the JVM's perspective - it has very little actual meaning at runtime. It's a way to tell the compiler that you're using an object in a specific capacity (usually, treating it as if it's a subclass of itself), which lets the compiler build in error behaviors, make sure that method signatures match, etc. Moreover, an object's type does not _change_ after it is typecast - only the way the compiler treats it (`(Object) fu` is still a `String`, the compiler just won't let you treat it like one any more)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I mean isn't that one of the two most essential properties of bar? That it points to the instance and that it has been restricted access to the instance by upcasting? There's methods to find out about the instance, but I don't see any built in way to report back on the casting information on the reference bar itself.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I determine that `bar` is typecast to `Object` at runtime?

You cannot determine that at runtime, since type casting has no effect on the reference in the `bar` variable or the object that it refers to<sup>1</sup>.

Calling `getClass()` on the object returns the object's actual type.

Solution:  There is no solution for the problem *as you stated it*.  If you explained what you were trying to achieve (e.g. with a larger example), maybe we could suggest an alternative approach.

---

<sup>1 - This is analogous to *real world* classification.  Suppose that I show you a cat.  Can you tell *just by looking at the cat* if I am currently (in my mind) classifying it as a *Felis Catus* or a member of the family *Felidae*, of the order *Carnivora*, of the class *Mammalia* and so on?  No.  The cat is *all* of those things and you can't tell what I am thinking by looking at the cat.  What I am thinking does not alter it one iota.</sup>

Comment: Solution: there is no problem ;-)

Comment: Well you could say that, but I am reserving judgment on whether there is any legitimate situation where it *might* be useful to know that type (dynamically).

Comment: It is a static construct. The programmer KNOWS what they wrote down. :man-shrugging-emoji

Comment: Well ... maybe.  It might be that the OP *actually* has something else in mind.  But unless they get back to us to clarify, we will never really know if this is a naive ... or deep ... question.

Comment: I just find it interesting that the program is aware that bar's access to the instance has been restricted, but there's no way for me to directly retrieve that information from bar itself. Why is important, but it's not everything. One utility I'm thinking of is bug checking a large program, it could be enlightening to jump in and ask whether a reference has been upcasted somewhere.

Comment: The program is *not* aware that "bar's access to the instance has been restricted", because it hasn't been. The *compiler's* ability to create code which uses that reference to access methods on `String` has been restricted, but you can still access them reflectively using `bar`.

Comment: @ProofByExhaustion - I think you need to think about my cat analogy some more.  When you cast `fu` to `Object` and assign it to `bar`, you are *telling* the program: "Think of `bar` as an `Object`.  Nothing more, nothing less."  Some other part of the program doesn't need to know what this part of the program is "thinking".  Therefore the JVM doesn't need to *represent* that information *at runtime*.

Comment: When I answered this question, I noted this: *"If you explained what you were trying to achieve (e.g. with a larger example), maybe we could suggest an alternative approach."*.  Do you have a real example / use-case for this, or is this just a "why can't I do <insert pointless thing> in Java" type of question?